# Plain Text "Text" property not displaying the content of a variable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I mean to have an app where, among other things, I display a value and allow to increment or decrement it. This value can be changed through a "settings" activity, via a Plain Text field. My issue is about displaying the current value as default text of the Plain Text.

Here's the XML code of the settings page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Current amount:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textCurRes"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editCurRes" />
    <Button
        android:text="OK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonOk" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code I use to send the values to the Settings activity:

```
int res = 5;
resSetButton.Click += delegate {
    Intent ResSetAct = new Intent(this, typeof(ResourceSettingsActivity));
    ResSetAct.PutExtra("res", res);
    StartActivity(ResSetAct);
};
```

And here's the code I use to retrieve the data in the other activity, and to display it:

```
string res = Intent.GetStringExtra("res");
EditText CurRes = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editCurRes);
CurRes.Text = res;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Plain Text “Text” property not displaying the content of a variable

Because here:

```
ResSetAct.PutExtra("res", res);
```

passing `int` using `PutExtra` but in next Activity try to get it using `GetStringExtra`.

Use `Intent.GetIntExtra` to get int value:

```
int res = Intent.GetIntExtra("res");
```